# Unable to install Cucumber Eclipse plugin inside VDI with no internet connection, getting error "requires 'bundle.org.eclipse.pde.ui 3.5.0

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, ui-automation

I am trying to install the Cucumber Eclipse plugin in my VDI (Virtual Desktop Infrastructure) which has no internet connection. However, I am getting an error message saying "requires 'bundle.org.eclipse.pde.ui 3.5.0, but it could not be found" when I try to install the plugin. My Eclipse version is Neon.3 Release (4.6.3).

I have tried installing the plugin through the "Install New Software" option in Eclipse and by manually downloading the plugin and trying to install it using the "Install" option in Eclipse. I have also checked that the "Contact all update sites during install to find required software" option is unchecked.

I have searched for solutions online, but most of them suggest installing the missing bundle through the Eclipse update site. However, as I am working on a VDI with no internet connection, this solution is not feasible for me.

Can anyone suggest a solution for installing the Cucumber Eclipse plugin in my VDI without an internet connection and resolving the error message?

Comment: You can't really install just the one plug-in. pde.ui is part of the plug-in development environment, the whole feature would need to be installed. In any case, But Neon is now 21 release old, how about installing a suitiable Eclipse 2023-03 from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/

Comment: The 2023-03 Eclipse IDE for Eclipse Committers would contain that feature.

Comment: Yes, upgrading the eclipse version worked. Thank you so much @greg-449 for the insight!! Thank you @nitind!!